# How to import a value in node js only after it is exported elsewhere sometime later?

Tags: node.js, import, async-await, request, export

I am learning SSO and trying this out without the conventional `User` class/object. I am new to asynchronous programming and having difficulty in managing the data flow. I am stuck at a point where I have successfully exported a `boolean` value, but my import (in another module) gets `undefined`. I suspect it is because import does not wait for the corresponding export statement to execute first. How do I make it and all subsequent code wait?

I don't know what to try in this case.

**Module that is exporting `usrFlag`**

```js
const request = require("request");
let usrFlag = false; // assuming user doesn't already exist.

function workDB(usr_id, usr_name, dateTimeStamp) {

  //some code excluded - preparing selector query on cloudant db

  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    if (body.docs.length == 0) addUsr(usr_id, usr_name, dateTimeStamp);
    else {
      xyz(true); //This user already exists in cloudant
      console.log('User already exists since', body.docs[0].storageTime);
    }
  });
}


async function setUsrFlag(val) { usrFlag = val; }

async function xyz(val) {
  await setUsrFlag(val);

  //module.exports below does not execute until usrFlag has the correct value.
  //so value is not exported until usrFlag has been properly set.

  console.log(usrFlag); 
  module.exports.usrFlag = usrFlag;
}
```

**Module that is importing this value**

```js
const usrP = require('../config/passport-setup');
const dbProcess = require('../dbOps/dbProcessLogic'); // <-- This is import

router.get('/google/redirect', passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {
  dbProcess.workDB(usrP.usrPrf.id, usrP.usrPrf.displayName, new Date());

  // Instead of true/false, I see undefined here.
  console.log(dbProcess.usrFlag); 
});
```

I expect the require function of import module to wait for export module to send it all the required values. However, I know that is probably not going to happen without me explicitly telling it to do so. My question is, how?

Comment: Your `console.log(dbProcess.usrFlag); ` statement runs before the `dbProcess.workDB(usrP.usrPrf.id, usrP.usrPrf.displayName, new Date());` function finishes execution. You can use promises to resolve this issue.

Only when the promise is fulfilled you should check the userFlag variable.

Comment: I know promises can help, may you please show some code, so I know exactly where and how to put them? I did something similar using async/await in export module, but didn't exactly use the promise, as I couldn't evaluate their proper use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I have just modified some of the code, so that I can work on it easily.

#### Module that is exporting `usrFlag`

```
// const request = require("request");
let usrFlag = false; // assuming user doesn't already exist.

function workDB(usr_id, usr_name, dateTimeStamp) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            xyz(true).then(function () {
                resolve('done');
            })
        }, 1000);
    });
}


function setUsrFlag(val) { usrFlag = val; }

function xyz(val) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setUsrFlag(val);
        module.exports.usrFlag = usrFlag;
        resolve('done');
    });

}

module.exports = {
    usrFlag,
    workDB
}
```

#### Module that is importing this `value`

```
const dbProcess = require('../dbOps/dbProcessLogic'); // <-- This is import

dbProcess.workDB().then(function () {
    console.log(dbProcess.usrFlag);
})
```

Now when you run the second file, you get usrFlag as true.
I have used setTimeout to imitate a request.

Sorry if I butchered up some of your code.

Comment: Okay, I modified my code including promises, but it isn't working as expected. What's the best way to show it to you? I can't possibly put all of it in comments.

Comment: You can use Repl.it [link](https://repl.it/@imnemo/nodejs-playground)
Here I have created one for mine. [link](https://repl.it/repls/ResponsibleNoisyBookmarks)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out here. Sorry, I was out sick and couldn't respond in time. That repl.it link really helped.